# Total impact factor and average impact factor per publications

Tags: publications, bibliometrics

I have been asked to compute the total impact factor and the average impact factor per publication with respect to the year of publication. Does anybody know how to compute these metrics? Also, a website that explains it is ok. The best would be a website that already provides me these informations, but I do not think that it exists!

Thank you!

Comment: Publications don't have impact factors; journals have impact factors.  You should ask the person who told you to do this for clarification.

Comment: Actually, it is written on a document and I cannot ask anyone. I suppose that, as you said, I have to compute these values considering the journal. The total impact factor is easy to find (I think I can find it on Web of Science, right?), but how can I compute the average?

Comment: I guess they mean total citations and total citations / citations. Something like that. But see above.

Comment: Ask the person who asked you. Our whoever is responsible for the document!

Comment: Total number of cites divided by the total number of publications?  You basically treat your publications list as a journal, and then calculate your IF the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that they are asking for the Impact Factors (IF) of the journals in which you published your papers. This, at least, is a widespread (but [ethically doubtful](https://sfdora.org/read/)) approach in research evaluation.

Anyway, to find the IFs per year, you need to have a subscription to Web of Science's *Journal Citation Reports* (JCR). (Usually, your university library provides an institutional subscription for you.)

1. Access JCR: https://jcr.clarivate.com
2. Enter the journal name and hit enter
3. Find the IF of the year of your publication

Here is an example of a journal which had an IF of 9.580 in the year 2018:

[image: A journal with an Impact Factor of 9.580 in the year 2018]